# MySQL 5.7 --> MariaDB 10.8 switch: mysqlcheck --check --extended hangs on table

Tags: performance, query-performance, mariadb, size, hang

Recently I switched from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.8 and it's been generally great as a drop-in replacement, but I've run into a problem: the process for a cron job that daily runs

```shell
/usr/bin/nice /usr/bin/ionice -c3 \
    /usr/bin/mysqlcheck \
        --all-databases --check --extended --check-only-changed --silent  2>&1
```

hangs indefinitely on one of the larger tables (981 MB). Here's the relevant output from showing the process list after four days since server restart (there's one process for each day the cron job runs):

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show full processlist;
+-------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id    | User         | Host            | db        | Command | Time   | State     | Info                                         | Progress |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
|  7719 | <cron user>  | localhost       | <db name> | Query   | 305690 | Executing | CHECK TABLE `<table name>`  EXTENDED CHANGED |    0.000 |
| 23567 | <cron user>  | localhost       | <db name> | Query   | 219929 | Executing | CHECK TABLE `<table name>`  EXTENDED CHANGED |    0.000 |
| 38185 | <cron user>  | localhost       | <db name> | Query   | 133529 | Executing | CHECK TABLE `<table name>`  EXTENDED CHANGED |    0.000 |
| 57790 | <cron user>  | localhost       | <db name> | Query   |  47127 | Executing | CHECK TABLE `<table name>`  EXTENDED CHANGED |    0.000 |
```

Nothing about this appears in `/var/log/mysql/` error logs.

### What next?

I'm hoping someone can point me to other things I can check to help diagnose the problem. If someone is kind enough to do so I'll update the question. Thanks!

##### OS and mariadb info

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.8.6-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?

Comment: Can you [install the debug symbol packages for 10.8.6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#installing-debug-info-packages-from-mariadbs-debian-or-ubuntu-repository) and gdb, and using that [grab a backtrace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/) and create a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org). Include the structure of `show create table <tablename>`.

Comment: Also sorry to say the `nice`/`ionice` will have no effect as the execution of `CHECK TABLE` is in the database itself. Looking forward to seeing your bug report.

Comment: @RickJames The tables are all InnoDB

Comment: @danblack I'll file a bug report as you instructed. Thanks!

Comment: @AJLivingston - Regardless of the outcome of this thread, you should change the cron script to avoid letting a new copy start before any previous ones finish.

Comment: @RickJames thanks that's an excellent idea

Comment: [cron locking suggestion](https://serverfault.com/a/461637/165495)

Comment: Please do a bug report. Even without a backtrace, the table structure might be sufficient to replicate the problem. Was the server previously upgrade from a version earlier than 5.7?

Comment: @danblack I created an issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30129 while I'm working on getting the backtrace. The server was always 5.7, and I've noted that in the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Stack trace [from the running process](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#getting-full-backtraces-for-all-threads-from-a-running-mariadbd-process) is probably what you're after. Online [community chat via zulip](https://mariadb.zulipchat.com) if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB Engineers in [MDEV-24402](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24402) added the implementation of `EXTENDED` for `CHECK TABLES` in InnoDB and this was included in the releases:

- MariaDB 10.6.11,
- MariaDB 10.7.7,
- MariaDB 10.8.6 and
- MariaDB 10.9.4.

And every stable version above those.

MySQL-5.7 and previous MariaDB versions parsed the `--extended` flag, but it had no effect on InnoDB tables.

Comment: Thanks @danblack! Can you clarify in your answer that the `--extended` flag did nothing when `--check` was present even in MySQL 5.7? That would address the original question completely.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted! And thanks again for all your help